# Unable to open new Google Colab Notebook

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have been trying to open a new notebook on google colab, and have been getting the error below, does anyone have solutions for this?

Unable to load Colaboratory

A network error occurred and the request could not be completed.
GapiError: A network error occurred and the request could not be completed.
at KB.Sq [as constructor] (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20211014-060056-RC00_403029548:637:845)
at new KB (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20211014-060056-RC00_403029548:1529:168)
at xa.program_ (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20211014-060056-RC00_403029548:1619:470)
at za (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20211014-060056-RC00_403029548:19:336)
at xa.throw_ (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20211014-060056-RC00_403029548:18:403)
at Aa.throw (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20211014-060056-RC00_403029548:20:248)
at g (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20211014-060056-RC00_403029548:63:155)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this error reproduce for you when loading Colab in an incognito window?

Comment: The error does not reproduce in an incognito window